# How to store and retrieve Array-list value in Android?

Tags: android, arraylist, bundle

In Android, Using Bundle to store and retrieve Array-list value, but i cannot retrieve this array-list value, please help me

Thanks in Advance

I tried this:

```
ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();                                     
al.add(""+StrValue);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Bundle value= new Bundle();                                                            
value.putStringArrayList("temp1", al);


 ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
 Bundle bundle =new Bundle();
 System.out.println("Retrieve Values are: "+bundle.getStringArrayList("temp1"));

Finally i got the result is Retrieve Values are (null)
```

Comment: post the actual code not psuedo code

Comment: Ok nandeesh, thanks for your reply

Comment: Now i edit this for your reference

Comment: @Minu see my edited answer, This code working for me, but i don't know this is correct way or not.

Comment: Is answer was helpful , accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,name.class);
i.putStringArrayListExtra("stringname", value);
startActivity(i);
```

And get data into Tabbar activity like

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        ArrayList<String> value = extras.getStringArrayList("stringname");
        Log.e(" array list value ", "" + value.size());
    }
```

And tab bar set Intent like

```
TabHost.TabSpec spec;
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("text");
Intent intent = new Intent(this, TargetActivity.class); 
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("string", value);
spec.setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

And get data in to TargetActivity like,

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        ArrayList<String> value = extras.getStringArrayList("string");
        Log.e(" array list value ", "" + value.size());
    }
```

Comment: Sorry to say this, i have using tabbar, now i store array value in 3rd tab then i retrieve the array value in 1st tab?

Comment: @Minu see my edited answer, This code working for me, but i don't know  this is correct way or not.

Comment: @Minu Is the answer was helpful?

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing a new Bundle. You should use the same bundle in which you have stored.

```
 Bundle bundle =new Bundle();
```

Instead do

```
 Bundle bundle  = value;
```